# Microservices - External access tokens stored in identity service, calendar service, or both?

Tags: asp.net, microservices, identity

I'm creating an application which, so far, has an identity service(using identityserver4), a front end, and a calendar service.

The user logs in via third party(say, google) and grants permissions to the application to manage their calendar.

When the user logs in, identityserver stores the access and refresh tokens in AspNetUserTokens.

**The question:**

> The calendar service needs access to do background tasks while the end
>   user is offline.  Should the access and refresh tokens be stored on
>   the calendar service as well as the identity service?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should create an id of your own for the user - and use that to request tokens from the ID server.

If you store those tokens in multiple services, you'll have multiple to update on expirations and other changes of such tokens. Store them in one spot, and make other services request them.

This also allows you to make authorization control over which services can access tokens for 3rd party activity by applying ACL check on the token service requests.

Your calendar service asks for a token, the token service says "Here's the 3rd party system info and token to access it". Your reporting service asks for a token for google calendar, the token service says "No, kthxbai" because it shouldn't be accessing such information. You can then easily audit as well every request for a users 3rd party resource access, by simply recording an audit log from the token service. This sort of auditing is really great to have for security.

By centralizing your storage of 3rd party tokens to a single service, you get a bunch of benefits around owning such important private user information in a single location - it becomes easier to secure, easier to monitor, easier to keep current, easier to scrub on user requests. It's your best solution, and I would encourage you to strongly monitor consumers of this service to make sure nobody writes clients which locally persist or cache such information. Alternatively, make the token service act as a request proxy so the token isn't even made available externally. Any way you go about it though, keep those tokens private in a single place (encrypted! secured! Do not back up!).